# Strange Issue of PyCharm

Tags: python, ide

My M1 MacBook Pro (2020) with 16 GB RAM has the latest version of PyCharm Professional installed on macOS Monterey.

I don't know when exactly this has started happening but here is the issue I am currently having with PyCharm:

When I try to write something to disk, e.g. write a list to a txt file, I need to wait for a few minutes for the newly created file to appear in the file browser on the left. Even if I click reload from the disk, it's still slow. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What’s your macOS? Do you have Pycharm Pro or Pycharm Community installed?

Comment: macOS Monterey. Pycharm Pro. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache : `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart` ?